# Explicit reverses in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My model looks like this:

```
App.Room = DS.Model.extend({
    title      : DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    rooms      : DS.hasMany('room', {
        async  : true,
        inverse: 'parent'
    }),
    parent     : DS.belongsTo('room')
});
```

Viewing existing records works, except creating new records.

I tried it like this:

```
var self = this,
        parent = this.get('content'),
        input = this.getProperties('title', 'description'),
        newRoom = this.store.createRecord('room', {
            title      : input.title,
            description: input.description,
            parent  : parent
        });

parent.get('rooms').then(function (rooms) {
    rooms.pushObject(newRoom);
    newRoom.save();
    parent.save();
    self.transitionToRoute('rooms');
});
```

But get this error:

```
Assertion Failed: You defined the 'parent' relationship on (subclass of DS.Model),
but multiple possible inverse relationships of type (subclass of DS.Model) were
found on (subclass of DS.Model).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relating an object to itself, so it's likely that Ember-Data's inverse guessing algorithm is getting confused. Declare the inverse on both explicitly.

```
App.Room = DS.Model.extend({
    rooms: DS.hasMany('room', {
        async: true,
        inverse: 'parent'
    }),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('room', {
        inverse: 'rooms'
    })
});
```

Because it's specifically mentioning the `parent` relationship, I'm assuming Ember-Data is thinking that it might be its own inverse.

Comment: ah yes, the example did only mention it for `DS.hasMany()`. thank you!